# Grafting only one of three branches of Mulberry

Tags: trees, grafting, shade, branches, mulberry

I have a white mulberry tree. I have planted it about 3 months ago. It was already pretty good in size and it is growing well. As you can see in the picture below, it has three main branches. I want to graft only one side branch with black mulberry. However, I don't want to disturb any part of the remaining two branches. I don't want to remove the branches or leaves of the other two branches. Because I like white mulberry more and just want to graft black mulberry for the sake of variety and fun.

Usually, I see people just remove everything from a plant when grafting. I don't want to do that.
Will it work? How much success chance do you think I have?

[image]